# android ndk dev use c traceroute command，why can't I receive the timeout echo？

Tags: android, android-ndk, traceroute

1. Create socket：socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP)
2. Phenomenon: by default I can send request and reply echo on this socket.

But for **traceroute** implement, when tt1 was set to 1, 2, 3, 4... then send request echo, at this time I assumed to receive the timeout echo, and furthermore I can obtain router address bypass.

But in my program, method recvfrom can't receive this timeout echo, and always been blocked, meanwhile when I capture packets using **wireshark**, I can capture this timeout echo precisely, and my question is why this echo couldn't be received by my program?

Question is in which part what org filter this timeout echo?

timeout reply echo can be captured by wireshark, but can't be obtain by my program, the detail as below png:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2T1G.png)

my source code below :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<pthread.h>

struct sockaddr_in dst_addr;
struct sockaddr_in recv_addr;
char icmp_pkt[1024] = {0};
char recv_pkt[1024] = {0};
int bytes = 56, nsend_pkt = 0, nrecv_pkt = 0;

int in_chksum(unsigned short *buf, int size);
int pack(int send_pkt, pid_t pid);
void send_traceroute(int sockfd, pid_t pid);
int unpack(int sockfd, char *recv_pkt, struct sockaddr_in *src_addr, int size, pid_t pid);
int recv_traceroutes(int sockfd, pid_t pid);
void tv_sub(struct timeval *out,struct timeval *in);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size = 50 * 1024;
    int errno = -1;
    int tried_times = 30, i = 0;
    int ttl = 0, ret = 0;
    int sockfd = 0;
    struct in_addr ipv4_addr;
    struct hostent *ipv4_host;
    struct protoent *protocol = NULL;
    pid_t pid;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./ping <host>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    if ((protocol = getprotobyname("icmp")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("unkown protocol\n");
        return -1;
    }
    pid = getpid();

    for(i = 0; i < tried_times; i++)
    {
        ttl = i + 1;
        if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, protocol->p_proto)) < 0)
        {
            printf("socket fail, need root\n");
            return -1;
        }
        setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &size, sizeof(size));
        setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));
        setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_TTL, &ttl, sizeof(ttl));

        memset(&dst_addr, 0, sizeof(dst_addr));
        dst_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        errno = inet_aton(argv[1], &ipv4_addr);
        if (errno == 0)
        {
            ipv4_host = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
            if (NULL == ipv4_host)
            {
                printf("connect: Invalid argument\n");
                return -1;
            }
            memcpy(&(dst_addr.sin_addr), ipv4_host->h_addr, sizeof(struct in_addr));
        }
        else
        {
            memcpy(&(dst_addr.sin_addr), &(ipv4_addr.s_addr), sizeof(struct in_addr));
        }
        printf("%d    ", i + 1);
        send_traceroute(sockfd, pid);
        ret = recv_traceroutes(sockfd, pid);
        close(sockfd);
        if(ret == 1)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int in_chksum(unsigned short *buf, int size)
{
    int nleft = size;
    int sum = 0;
    unsigned short *w = buf;
    unsigned short ans = 0;

    while(nleft > 1)
    {
        sum += *w++;
        nleft -= 2;
    }
    if (nleft == 1)
    {
        *(unsigned char *) (&ans) = *(unsigned char *)w;
        sum += ans;
    }
    sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xFFFF);
    sum += (sum >> 16);
    ans = ~sum;
    return ans;
}

int pack(int send_pkt, pid_t pid)
{
    struct icmp *pkt = (struct icmp *)icmp_pkt;

    pkt->icmp_type = ICMP_ECHO;
    pkt->icmp_cksum = 0;
    pkt->icmp_seq = htons(nsend_pkt);
    pkt->icmp_id = pid;
    pkt->icmp_cksum = in_chksum((unsigned short *)pkt, bytes + 8);

    return bytes + 8;
}

void send_traceroute(int sockfd, pid_t pid)
{
    int send_bytes = 0;
    int ret = -1;

    nsend_pkt++;
    send_bytes = pack(nsend_pkt, pid);
    ret = sendto(sockfd, icmp_pkt, send_bytes, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dst_addr, sizeof(dst_addr));
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("send fail\n");
        sleep(1);
        return ;
    }
}

int unpack(int sockfd, char *recv_pkt, struct sockaddr_in *src_addr, int size, pid_t pid)
{
    struct iphdr *ip = NULL;
    int iphdrlen;
    struct icmp *icmp;
    struct timeval *tvsend;
    double rtt;
    struct sockaddr peer_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *tmp_addr = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    memset(&peer_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

    ip = (struct iphdr *)recv_pkt;
    iphdrlen = ip->ihl<<2;
    icmp = (struct icmp *)(recv_pkt + iphdrlen);

    size -= iphdrlen;
    if (size < 8)
    {
        printf("ICMP size is less than 8\n");
        return -1;
    }

    len = sizeof(peer_addr);

    if ((icmp->icmp_type == ICMP_TIME_EXCEEDED))
    {    
        tmp_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)src_addr;
        printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(tmp_addr->sin_addr));
    }
    else if((icmp->icmp_type == ICMP_ECHOREPLY) && (icmp->icmp_id == pid))
    {
        tmp_addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)src_addr;
        printf("%s\n", inet_ntoa(tmp_addr->sin_addr));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int recv_traceroutes(int sockfd, pid_t pid)
{
    fd_set rd_set;
    struct timeval time;
    time.tv_sec = 5;
    time.tv_usec = 0;
    int ret = 0, nread = 0,recv_len = 0;

    recv_len = sizeof(recv_addr);
    FD_ZERO(&rd_set);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &rd_set);
    ret = select(sockfd + 1, &rd_set, NULL, NULL, &time);
    if (ret <= 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &rd_set))
    {
        nread = recvfrom(sockfd, recv_pkt, sizeof(recv_pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr,(socklen_t *) &recv_len);
        if (nread < 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        ret = unpack(sockfd, recv_pkt, &recv_addr, nread, pid);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your code? It might help to debug the problem

Comment: U can refresh the page and see the code